# How does Java improve over C++ in the area of portability?

Tags: java, c++, compiler, jvm

I was reading through a Java book by author Herbert Schildt and he writes how the advantage of Java over C++ in portabilaty is that while C++ can be run anywhere, it still requires each program to be compiled with a compiler that was created for that CPU, and creating compilers is difficult, while Java doesn't need to be compiled for each CPU as long as there is a JVM for that processor.

My question is how is this an improvement? Doesn't the JVM need to be compiled for each architecture anyway, so you still require a individual compiler for each type of CPU? So what is this advantage?

Comment: _I_ don't have to compile the JVM on every platform, someone else has already done it for me. This means I can just distribute my Java programs as is, and they'll be supported by every platform with a JVM.

Comment: My question is in reference to what he wrote about the difficulty in creating compilers, don't you still require a separate compiler for each architecture to implement the jvm?

Comment: Of course, but the point of having a virtual machine is that you have a program that's supposed to run Java code the same way on every platform.  The effort to make it work that way happens once per platform instead of once per application per platform.  That's the theory, anyway; people do manage to write broken VMs, though.

Comment: See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/11/18/why-il/) on the subject.

Comment: Write once, debug everywhere.

Comment: See http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/111080/122484

Comment: In most cases where Java has an advantage, it usually boils down to simplicity (if you boil it down hard enough).  In this case, the Java team do all the heavy lifting portability to you, and (ideally) provide a common environment on every platform that supports Java.  [There have been cases where this isn't 100% guaranteed, though.  I remember reading about something that acted slightly differently on 32-bit systems than it did on 64-bit systems, for example.]

Comment: In practice someone else has made the compiler already, but for you the application developer there's still a benefit, because you still don't need to compile your program for different CPU architectures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The advantage to you is that if there is already a good JVM for of all your target platforms, all you really need to do is release your Java application once and it should just run on all of them. You shouldn't need to do anything else!

...of course, that's the *theory*. In reality, you probably should *test* on each target platform before releasing. Just in case your application depends (intentionally or accidentally) on OS-specific functionality.

With C++, it's up to *you* to ensure that you compile your application separately for each platform, with the appropriate platform-specific compiler and libraries. And then test for each one.

The advantage that Java could give you here goes away if there is no suitable JVM for your target platform.

Comment: Your answer gives IMHO a wrong impression. In reality, I am pretty sure the majority of portability issues in Java programs are not caused by different JVMs, but by differences in the underlying operating systems and hardware - JVMs cannot decouple the programs completely from these. So one does not just have to test on each platform, but actually remove the portability issues.

Comment: @DocBrown This is only true when your code depends on operating system functionality.  This is the fundamental reason behind why Java UIs have been so disapointing.  If you stick to the functionality defined in the JVM spec and use a compliant JVM, you won't have portability issues.  I've run the same code (much of which was not written by me) on Windows, AS400, Linux, AIX with 0 issues many times.

Comment: @JimmyJames: you got me wrong, I am not saying you cannot write portable code (if you know what you are doing). However, I think it is much more likely to accidentally make your program depend on OS or hardware specifics than accidentally making it depend on JVM specifics.

Comment: @DocBrown That hasn't been my experience but that might be due to my area of concentration.  The only portability issue I can recall in the last 10 years of so was related to bad API design where image generation methods are embedded in the UI classes and you get headless environment exceptions on servers trying to generate image files in some environments.

Comment: @DocBrown: the JVm being unable to decouple the program from the OS is a failure of the JVM's (Or Java's, or Sun's, etc) promise. It is supposed to provide that decoupling.

Comment: @whatsisname: well, the AFAIK the primary purpose of the JVM is to decouple from the underlying processor architecture. The decoupling from the OS is part of the JRE. But you are missing my point. It is very simple to create a Java program which is not portable, for example, by trying to run an external command which is only available on one OS, and not on the other. That is not a bug of the JVM or the JRE.

Comment: ... so this answer could IMHO be heavily improved by replacing "Just in case your application depends on JVM features ..." by "in case your application depends accidentally on features of the underlying OS or hardware". In the current form, the answer gives the IMHO wrong impression it is really hard to write non-portable programs.

Answer (score 5):

If you have 10 programs and 10 platforms, you need 100 binaries for C++ (compiling each program to each platform), but only 20 binaries for Java (10 of your programs to Java, 10 of the JVM to the platforms … and those latter 10 are probably not even created by you, *and* the cost for compiling them can be amortized across all the other programs that also target the JVM).

Comment: I think you mean *binaries*. If you have 10 programs and 10 platforms, you need 100 binaries. etc. A port implies rewriting large parts of the source code, which is not needed for the typical C++ program.

Answer (score 5):

> How does Java improve over C++ in the area of portability?

It's also worth addressing this larger question. The two languages have different "portability" goals.

**Java** has a goal of *"write once, run anywhere."* It aims to download programs to a wide variety of devices and have them *produce the same results*. The Java Language Spec and VM Spec go to great lengths to make Java programs portable in this sense. (In practice, there are library bugs that diminish this to "write once, debug anywhere.")

**C++** has an unwritten goal of *"run fast anywhere"* but it's not concerned with producing the same results or avoiding failures. The C++ language goes to great lengths to make programs run fast on a wide variety of devices, but the meaning of C++ programs varies by compiler and target device. This is a different sense of "portability."

Examples of C++ semantics that differ by compiler and target:

- `short`, `int`, and `long` have differing widths, may be big- or little-endian, may do twos complement, ones complement, or magnitude + sign math, and `>>` may do a signed or unsigned shift, so integer math produces differing results
- various cases cause arbitrary [Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) (which means the compiler is allowed to generate any code, say, fall through to code that produces uncontrolled engine acceleration): using an uninitialized variable, signed integer overflow, oversized shift count, dereferencing a null pointer, out of bounds array access, stack overflow, and type aliasing
- a statement like `a[i++] = f(i++) + i` does not have a specified evaluation order so it doesn't have a well defined meaning, and if `f()` throws an exception, C++ doesn't specify which side effects will have occurred or not, e.g. what `i` will contain
- struct packing layout
- compiler switches change the meaning of the code (e.g. enum size)

Comment: Note that despite this, C++ guarantees that each integral type will support a specific minimum range (which in turn imply a specific minimum size), meaning that their behavior is always identical when operating within this range (`char` is at least 8 bits, `short` and `int` are at least 16 bits, `long` is at least 32 bits, and `long long` is at least 64 bits; signed and unsigned variants of each have the same alignment and width, with unqualified `char` being... weird).

Comment: As of C++11, specifically-sized types are also available (`intX_t` / `uintX_t`, `int_leastX_t` / `uint_leastX_t`, and `int_fastX_t` / `uint_fastX_t`, where `X` is 8, 16, 32, or 64), when needed... but they get a bit wonky on platforms that don't support types whose sizes are a multiple of 8.  The exact-size ones _only_ exist if they can be _exactly_ the specified size.  The `leastX` ones are the smallest supported size that is at least `X`.  [And the `fastX` ones are always wonky; they're generally the platform's word size, or _might_ be `least8` if `X` is 8.]

Comment: So, even with the types intended specifically to guarantee that they can be treated as the specified number of bits, their size still isn't the same on every platform.  ...Suffice it to say, Java doesn't have this issue.

Comment: A big one IME: Java's `String` is defined to be encoded in UTF-16.  C++ has a character encoding schism where Microsoft likes to use UTF-16 `wchar_t` strings and the *nix world prefers to use UTF-8 `char` strings.

Answer (score 3):

It's less about code and operating systems, more about compiled binaries and processor architectures.

In C++, we can write code that is portable (works on Windows, Linux, and Mac, and on most popular processor architectures i386, amd64, ARM etc.), but the **compiler's output is bound to specific combination of operating system and processor architecture**. We must compile the program separately for each combination.

In Java, code gets compiled into Java Byte Code. This **byte code can be run on Java Virtual Machine (VM) running on any hardware/OS configuration**. The VM must still be separately compiled for each processor architecture and OS, but it's always done by VM provider. There are differences between VMs from different providers, so code and byte code is always portable in the context of single VM provider. It's possible to write a Java program that runs on multiple VM implementations, but differences must be taken into account.

In summary:

1. Single source is easy, single program binary is harder,
2. Java adds cross-vm-implementation issues to already present cross-os issues.